# Laravel implementing simple MiddleWare doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, output, middleware, laravel-5.5

In my web application i'm trying to check local in URLs, for example:

In this URL as `http://www.sample.com/aboutUs` we don't have any locale such as `en`,`ru` or etc like: `http://www.sample.com/en/aboutUs`.

In my web app I implemented simple middleware to check that and fix URL when URLs don't have them:

```
class language
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd($request);
        $locale = $request->segment(1);

        if (!array_key_exists($locale, config('app.locales'))) {
            $segments = $request->segments();
            $segments[0] = config('app.fallback_locale');
            return redirect(implode('/', $segments));
        }

        app()->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Which that registered into:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
        ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'language' => \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
    ...
];
```

This middleware only work when we have locale in URL and my code as:

```
Route::get('/showContent/aboutUs', ['middleware' => 'language', function()
{
    dd('asda');
    //
}]);
```

This doesn't work and I don't see any `dd` output

1:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/showContent/aboutUs', 'HomeController@aboutUs');
});
```

2:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'language'], function () {
    Route::get('/showContent/aboutUs', 'HomeController@aboutUs');
});
```

for all my solutions i get this output:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: return redirect(implode('/', $segments)); what it will be written?  does this route is define? may be these one is causing the error.

Comment: @MeeraTank thats for urls which thay havn not locale

Comment: Could you add the output of `php artisan route:list` to your post? I suspect that you need to register every route twice, once with a {locale} prefix, and once without.

Comment: @sisve output is very long result